# print only variables with value

Tags: bash

```
value1=yellow
value2=
value3=red
value4=pink
value5=
```

I need to print only the contents of string with values (=value1, value3, value4)

```
#!/bin/bash
value1=yellow
value2=
value3=red
value4=pink
value5=

for a in {1..5}
do
echo $value$a
done
```

Comment: What is `valueN=…`? Is it a file that you parse?

Comment: Perhaps you should consider using an [array](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-use-arrays-in-bash-script)...

Answer (score 4):

You can use [indirect reference](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) the variable and then check if it's empty.

```
#!/bin/bash

value1=yellow
value2=
value3=red
value4=pink
value5=

for a in {1..5}
do
    var=value$a
    val=${!var}
    [[ -n ${val} ]] && echo "${val}"
done
```